# iTunes doesn't start

Tags: itunes, podcasts

When I try to open my iTunes on Windows 7 it opens in the Podcasts section and asks for a Userid/Pass for trancemix.org. This was a free Podcast I subscribed to last time I used iTunes. When I cancel the Login request my iTunes Hangs and I am forced to kill it. Is there a way via command line I can unsubscribe this Podcast Or any other way to get rid of this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the *detailed procedure* outlined by Apple on [iTunes for Windows Vista or Windows 7: Troubleshooting unexpected quits, freezes, or launch issues](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1717).

It begins with starting iTunes in Safe Mode and then proceeds to other steps like removing iTunes Preference files, creating a new library, recreating a library and so on.

If you seem to get stuck in this process, I would suggest creating a new library and adding your existing content to it. You would lose your playlists, ratings, etc. Here are the steps:

1. Hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when launching iTunes (from the Start Menu or Task Bar or Windows Explorer).
2. Click on the **Create Library...** button and start iTunes.
3. Drag and drop all your media folders into the iTunes window. If you configured iTunes to organize and copy media, your media files would be under the **%userprofile%\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media** folder. You can also do this by going to the **File > Add Folder to Library...** menu option and choosing the folders.